# About mercy killing in islam

Tags: quran, torture

One of my friends is hypnotised and black magic was maybe cast on him. His parents along with the entire society are after him and forcing him to live life as a slave.
He has no way out and he might end up doing crimes.
Is suicide permissible as a last resort as he has no means to live and noone is helping him.He's been kidnapped by a gang many times.
Need Quran and hadith reference's

Comment: No it doesn't as the person is doing suicide to be protected from a gang.

Comment: The answer there specifies that there is nothing that allows suicide. Nothing at all. Gangs make no difference.

Comment: I totally agree with @The Z. Islam prohibits suicide by all means. The goal does not justify the means.